# Iterating through Resultsets in threads cause Exceptions. ResultSets of queries to Hive using JDBC connections

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, hive

Doing an evaluation of Hive and its features.
Theres a use-case where I need to iterate through a resultset in a separate thread. I can have many ResultSets and spawn a thread to process each one of them.
Below is the code I have written for this use case.

```
public class ConcurrentRSIteration2 {
private static String[] tableNames = 
    { 
        "random_data1",
        "random_data2",
        "random_data3",
        "random_data4"
    };

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    Class.forName(driverName);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default", "hive", "");

    int length = tableNames.length;

    StringBuilder[] sql = new StringBuilder[length];
    PreparedStatement[] stmt = new PreparedStatement[length];
    Thread[] rsIterators = new Thread[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sql[i] = new StringBuilder().
                    append("select * from ").
                    append(tableNames[i]);
        stmt[i] = con.prepareStatement(sql[i].toString());
        RSIterator2 rsIterator = new RSIterator2(stmt[i].executeQuery());

        rsIterators[i] = new Thread(rsIterator);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        rsIterators[i].start();
    }
}
}

class RSIterator2 implements Runnable {

private ResultSet rs;

public RSIterator2(ResultSet rs) {
    this.rs = rs;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(this.hashCode() + " : " + rs);
        System.out.println(this.hashCode() + " : RS iteration started.");
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(this.hashCode() + " : RS iteration done.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Below is the stacktrace of the exception.

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:376)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:453)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:501)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:488)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:360)
    at hivetrial.RSIterator2.run(ConcurrentRSIteration2.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

I am new to Hive and might have overlooked few things. Trying to understand this Exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire approach is founded on a fallacy. You are using a single connection to execute multiple queries. The database server will therefore sequentialize all the data returned, in the order the queries were executed. Using multiple threads to process a single stream doesn't begin to make sense.

You're also never closing the statements or the connection.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for your response. Does hive sequentialize data the same way any Oracle or any other Database server does,

Comment: How can it *not* sequentialize the data? There's only one connection.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, every time you have a resultset open you have a cursor opened. Everytime you do rs.next() you advance its cursor. I think the code should work fine in Oracle, Since you will have 4 different cursors opened and it shouldn't matter if its sequentialized or not. Somehow this doesnt work in Hive.

Comment: @RoshanVinil *There is only one connection.* It doesn't make sense to treat it as a multithreaded resource. It isn't. You've already accepted an answer that says so. How you think it should work is of no relevance.

Answer (score 2):

Classes in `java.sql` package are not thread safe.

Separating a `ResultSet` from its companion `Statement` is a bad idea.  You should query, load the rows into an object or data structure, then close both in a finally block in separate try/catch blocks.

I would be remiss if I failed to point out connection pools. Why limit yourself to just one?

Comment: Hi duffymo, thanks for your response. This was just a rough code with a lotta copy paste. I see that I have a similar code in the product working fine, where there's just a single connection and a lotta analytical queries executed using the same connection. Each resultset is then passed on to a thread for processing. This works fine and is in production. I have also tried doing what was suggested by you(not the pooling) in my sample. I get the same exception. Was wondering if this is a limitation of Hive.

Comment: I don't know what "works fine" looks like, but this is not a good way to go.  I don't know what you did that produced the same outcome.  I'll assume you did not implement what I had in mind correctly until there's new evidence.

Comment: All right, this is exactly what I did. The same code in the question moved the statement to the thread and all the threads share the same connection. This works in Oracle, but doesn't work in Hive.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/299971/JDBC/databases/connection-object-multiple-threads), this is exactly what I want to replicate in Hive.